# How to get Twilio API SID

Tags: api, twilio, sid

I just created a free Twilio account but I chose an option without code support.
I have got
-Account SID
-Auth Token
but the required API SID is not provided to me.
I created some API Key. Is this API SID or please, advise where I can find API SID?
Do I need to change my account to use code support? How to change it?

Thanks,
Yury.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are using the REST API, you should be fine to use the Account SID and Auth Token that are available on your [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console).

If you need an API SID (or an API Key and API Secret), because you need to generate an [Access Token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens), then you were right to create an [API key](https://www.twilio.com/console/project/api-keys). When you have created the API Key you will see a SID and a secret, as pointed out in this screenshot:

[image: The page after you create an API Key in the Twilio console. The API Key SID is labelled "SID" and the secret is labelled "Secret"]

Make sure to copy the API Key Secret as that won't be shown again. Then check the box to say you have it copied and click "Done".

You don't need to change your account to use this, all Twilio accounts support using the API.